# Finding the names of objects in the Resource database

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2019, dmv, system-databases

I'm looking at the [sys.dm_exec_function_stats](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-exec-function-stats-transact-sql) view to find scalar function stats. That view also includes rows from a database with an id **32767**, which I've found is the [Resource database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/resource-database?view=sql-server-ver16#accessing-the-resource-database).

Some of these IDs can be passed to `OBJECT_NAME()` or `OBJECT_DEFINITION()` Metadata functions but some IDs return `NULL`

```
SELECT SERVERPROPERTY('ResourceVersion')  AS 'ResourceVersion'
SELECT SERVERPROPERTY('ResourceLastUpdateDateTime') AS 'ResourceLastUpdateDateTime' 

SELECT 
    defs.database_id
    , defs.object_id
    , OBJECT_NAME(defs.object_id) AS objName
    , OBJECT_DEFINITION(defs.object_id) AS objDef
    , OBJECT_NAME(defs.object_id, defs.database_id) AS objNameDB
    , OBJECT_DEFINITION(defs.object_id, defs.database_id) AS objDefDB
FROM sys.dm_exec_function_stats AS defs
WHERE defs.database_id = 32767
```

[image]

I can find the `fn_hadr_is_primary_replica` function (object_id = -665919249) in the `sys.all_objects` or in `sys.all_sql_modules`, but not the object_id = -706609674.

Is there any way how to find the object name or definition of the -706609674?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In my instance, object id -706609674 is `sys.fn_cdc_jobs`.

The resource database is just another database with files you can make a copy of and attach under a different name.

The files are named `mssqlsystemresource.mdf` and `mssqlsystemresource.ldf`.

You can find them in the subdirectory `\MSSQL\Binn` for your installation.

Alternatively, run your commands from the DAC.